# Running ksh script inside a perl code is not working

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have a Korn shell script at a location like `/opt/apps/abc/folder/properties.env`. I can execute it from Unix bash using the dot command:

```
. /opt/apps/abc/folder/properties.env
```

This works.

I have a Perl script `abc.pl` from which I am calling the script `properties.env`. I tried the following different:

1. `system('/usr/bin/ksh','-c', '. /opt/apps/abc/folder/properties.env');`
2. `/usr/bin/ksh -c /opt/apps/abc/folder/properties.env;`
3. `system('. /opt/apps/abc/folder/properties.env');`

None of the above work. I don't want to use `exec` because I want to return to the Perl script. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) What result do you expect? 2) What result do you get instead?

Comment: How about `system('/usr/bin/ksh','-c', '/opt/apps/abc/folder/properties.env');` ?

Comment: I tried this too. didn't work.

Comment: There are some commands in the ksh script which set the environment properties. I want that to run successfully.

Comment: It's impossible to set environment variables from a child process (and you can start ksh script from perl only as a child process). The only way to extract their settings manually from script and set them in a perl script. Sorry for English.

Comment: Sourcing a shell script from another shell script (or an interactive shell) is *not* the same as executing it. What your asking is equivalent of trying to `require 'script.ksh';` in a perl script; it won't work because a ksh script isn't a perl script and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

The environment changes will only last as long as the life of the ksh session spawned by the `system`  command. If you want the environment changes to affect the Perl script, then you have to source that file *before* you launch the Perl program.

Answer (score 0):

If you need those environment variables in your perl code, (not in the environment where you called perl), you can also read and parse that properties.env and set the environment in the %ENV variable.

e.g

```
$ENV{'ENV_VAR1'}=VALUE_OF_ENV_VAR1
```

using system() spawn another process, as the other poster said. changing environment in the child does not affect the parent.